# Can I leave the airport and take a taxi with BRL Reais?

Tags: airports, money, payment-cards, taxis, argentina

I'm going to travel from Brazil to Argentina.

1. I have plans to live in Argentina until the end of the year but what I still do not know is if I can take a taxi or eat something at the Buenos Aires airport and take a bus to other province paying in reais or using my debit card from a common bank in Brazil (Caixa Econômica Federal). I do not have credit card.

or

2. My girlfriend has an account in Argentina, could she take a taxi for me and pay for the internet or for an application? She lives in Mendoza.

References:

[Having pesos before arriving in Argentina](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/94269/having-pesos-before-arriving-in-argentina)

Comment: You can exchange your money from reais to pesos in the airport.

Comment: You talk about ATM' or anything else? How much in taxes?

Comment: No, I was talking about currency exchange offices that exist in most international airports. See for example https://www.ifly.com/ezeiza-international-airport/ATM-banks-currency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to exchange you reais into pesos at a currency exchange office in the airport. These exist at most (if not all) international airports.

Here are some links for Ezeiza:

- https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g312741-i979-k4070198-Currency_exchange_at_Buenos_Aires_EZE_airport-Buenos_Aires_Capital_Federal_District.html
- https://www.ifly.com/ezeiza-international-airport/ATM-banks-currency

Fees for exchanging money vary by agency.

You can also contact your bank to ask them whether your debit card works abroad.

Comment: I really care about taxes for this transactions.

Comment: Really you need to check if your debit card will work. I have a Banco do Brasil debit card and it works fine abroad Brazil (US, Chile, Argentina, Uruguai and so on). You need to have in the mind that you will pay 6,38% IOF tax to use it. BRL Reais is not the official currency in Argentina, but there are a bunch of Restaurants, cabs and so on that accept it.

Comment: @FrancisRodrigues sorry to tell you, but there is probably no way you'll be able to make the currency exchange without paying some fees.

Comment: I care about taking a taxi at the airport and paying for a bus ticket to Mendoza.  I see no other way to change by weights in ATM's.